# Why logrotate copied one file but didn't create a new one?

Tags: linux, docker, nginx, logging, logrotate

I run logrotate in a nginx docker container.

```
FROM nginx:1.16.1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron logrotate
ADD logrotate /etc/logrotate.d/nginx

CMD ["cron", "-f"]
```

logrotate file:

```
/var/log/nginx/access.json {
        missingok
        rotate 7
        notifempty
        sharedscripts
        postrotate
                if [ -f /var/run/nginx.pid ]; then
                        kill -USR1 `cat /var/run/nginx.pid`
                fi
        endscript
```

First of all, the log files under `/var/log/nginx/` are:

- access.json
- access.log
- error.log

After run rotate command

```
logrotate -v /etc/logrotate.d/nginx
```

The files became:

- access.json.1
- access.log
- error.log

`access.json` disappeared. And the verbose is:

```
reading config file /etc/logrotate.d/nginx
Reading state from file: /var/lib/logrotate/status
Allocating hash table for state file, size 64 entries
Creating new state

Handling 1 logs

rotating pattern: /var/log/nginx/access.json  100 bytes (7 rotations)
empty log files are not rotated, old logs are removed
considering log /var/log/nginx/access.json
  Now: 2020-12-23 10:33
  Last rotated at 2020-12-23 10:32
  log needs rotating
rotating log /var/log/nginx/access.json, log->rotateCount is 7
dateext suffix '-20201223'
glob pattern '-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
renaming /var/log/nginx/access.json.7 to /var/log/nginx/access.json.8 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 7),
old log /var/log/nginx/access.json.7 does not exist
renaming /var/log/nginx/access.json.6 to /var/log/nginx/access.json.7 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 6),
old log /var/log/nginx/access.json.6 does not exist
renaming /var/log/nginx/access.json.5 to /var/log/nginx/access.json.6 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 5),
old log /var/log/nginx/access.json.5 does not exist
renaming /var/log/nginx/access.json.4 to /var/log/nginx/access.json.5 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 4),
old log /var/log/nginx/access.json.4 does not exist
renaming /var/log/nginx/access.json.3 to /var/log/nginx/access.json.4 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 3),
old log /var/log/nginx/access.json.3 does not exist
renaming /var/log/nginx/access.json.2 to /var/log/nginx/access.json.3 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 2),
renaming /var/log/nginx/access.json.1 to /var/log/nginx/access.json.2 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 1),
renaming /var/log/nginx/access.json.0 to /var/log/nginx/access.json.1 (rotatecount 7, logstart 1, i 0),
old log /var/log/nginx/access.json.0 does not exist
log /var/log/nginx/access.json.8 doesn't exist -- won't try to dispose of it
renaming /var/log/nginx/access.json to /var/log/nginx/access.json.1
running postrotate script
logrotate_script: 3: kill: No such process

error: error running shared postrotate script for '/var/log/nginx/access.json '
```

I created a file `/var/run/nginx.pid` and set a number into it manually to test, but still not work.

Comment: Looks like nginx is stopping as a result of the access.json rename. You will also need to restart nginx to get another access.json file

Comment: @RamanSailopal I got the reason. I added `CMD ["cron", "-f"]` into the `Dockerfile`. So nginx can't start after launched the container. But if I don't set it, `cron` service can't run. Do you know how to run it with nginx together?